# Open form in access using criteria?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is it possible to open a form in MS ACCESS 2007 using a where clause which consists of "and".
Suppose I want to open a form based on two criteria, i.e. I have a dropdown on a form that is used to open a form on the basis of the value selected but this dropdown looks up the selected value in another dropdown and so the Open form criteria should should include the selections in both the dropdowns.Is it possible to do so?
Is the following correct?

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Me.Name, , , "[A_PRIORITY] = '" & _
   cboPrior & "'" AND "[A_LOCATION] = '" & _
   cboLocate & "'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many quotes, it should look like:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Me.Name, , , "[A_PRIORITY] = '" & _ 
   cboPrior & "' AND [A_LOCATION] = '" & _ 
   cboLocate & "'"
```

All commands and keywords are inside the main quotes, only variables are outside.